# magento2.3.4 The number of shopping carts is not displayed

Tags: magento2

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Interceptor::setExtensionAttributes(), 0 passed in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mgtcs/development/vendor/magento/framework/DataObject.php on line 207 and exactly 1 expected in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mgtcs/development/generated/code/Magento/Quote/Model/Quote/Interceptor.php:1398
Stack trace:
#0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mgtcs/development/vendor/magento/framework/DataObject.php(207): Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Interceptor->setExtensionAttributes()
#1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mgtcs/development/generated/code/Magento/Quote/Model/Quote/Interceptor.php(2000): Magento\Framework\DataObject->setDataUsingMethod('customer_prefix', NULL)
#2 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mgtcs/development/vendor/magento/framework/DataObject/Copy.php(368): Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Interceptor->setDataUsingMethod('customer_prefix', NULL)
#3 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mgtcs/development/vendor/magento/framework/DataObject/Copy.php(245): Magento\Framework\DataObje in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mgtcs/development/generated/code/Magento/Quote/Model/Quote/Interceptor.php on line 1398
```

Comment: where above error comes?

Comment: It seems that the global shopping cart does not display the red quantity

Comment: There is no problem when you are not logged in. The shopping cart items are not displayed when you log in. The shopping cart icon is always gray